# How to configure multiple miners on a single network laptop/router?

Tags: miner-configuration

I have 2 S9's, a router and laptop.

Do the S9's have separate IP addresses or just one network IP for both miners? I realize this sounds stupid, however, I cant figure out how to apply 2 IP addresses to the Bitmain s/w set up. All the set up examples only show 1 miner.